# Who is speaking in Ex. 3:17?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, yetziat-mitzrayim, parashas-shemos

*Sh'mos* 3:15–18 reads:

> ‏15 וַיֹּאמֶר עוֹד אֱלֹהִים אֶל מֹשֶׁה…. 16 לֵךְ וְאָסַפְתָּ אֶת זִקְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְאָמַרְתָּ אֲלֵהֶם יהוה אֱלֹהֵי אֲבֹתֵיכֶם נִרְאָה אֵלַי… לֵאמֹר פָּקֹד פָּקַדְתִּי אֶתְכֶם וְאֶת הֶעָשׂוּי לָכֶם בְּמִצְרָיִם. 17 וָאֹמַר אַעֲלֶה אֶתְכֶם מֵעֳנִי מִצְרַיִם אֶל אֶרֶץ הַכְּנַעֲנִי וְהַחִתִּי וְהָאֱמֹרִי וְהַפְּרִזִּי וְהַחִוִּי וְהַיְבוּסִי אֶל אֶרֶץ זָבַת חָלָב וּדְבָשׁ. 18 וְשָׁמְעוּ לְקֹלֶךָ…‏

I'm unsure of how to read this. Specifically, the last part of pasuk 16 is *Hashem* quoting *Moshe* quoting *Hashem*. Is *pasuk* 17 the same, or is it just *Hashem* quoting *Moshe*? That is, do we read the passage as this —

> God said further to Moses:
>
> > … Go gather the elders of Israel and tell them:
> >
> > > God, the god of your fathers, appeared to me… saying:
> > >
> > > > I paid attention to you and to what was done to you in Egypt. And I have said [*or:* say]:
> > > >
> > > > > I will raise you from the poverty of Egypt….
> >
> > And they will heed your voice….

— or as this —

> God said further to Moses:
>
> > … Go gather the elders of Israel and tell them:
> >
> > > God, the god of your fathers, appeared to me… saying:
> > >
> > > > I paid attention to you and to what was done to you in Egypt.
> > >
> > > And I have said [*or:* say]:
> > >
> > > > I will raise you from the poverty of Egypt….
> >
> > And they will heed your voice….

—?

Comment: I'm getting confused with your second example: Did you not mean >>>> I paid attention to you and to what was done to you in Egypt. And I have said: >>>>> I will raise you from the poverty of Egypt…

Comment: I'm not sure how your second presentation of the pasuk makes as much sense as the first, since there you attribute to Moses a line that was instead said by God... Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Regardless, it would seem like the first example is the correct one because  a) It's a new verse. a) Why would Moshe tell the Zekaynim that Hashem said they would listen to him?

Comment: @Michoel re your 1st comment: That's the first version I wrote. Re your 2d comment, (a): I don't understand what you're referring to by "it". Re your 2d comment, (b): _Moshe_ wasn't saying that according to either rendering I offer. That was clearly just _Hashem_ telling _Moshe_ the elders would listen to _Moshe_.

Comment: @ShimonbM I'm suggesting _Hashem_ was telling _Moshe_ to tell the elders that he (_Moshe_) planned to take them from Egypt. I agree that the first presentation seems more natural, but I see nothing wrong with the second.

Comment: Alright, I think I get your question now. So you are suggesting that Moshe was told to say to the elders that he (Moshe) had (previously) said "I will raise you from the poverty of Egypt". Do we find anywhere that Moshe had said such a thing in the past?

Comment: @Michoel, וָאֹמַר, although I translated it as "And I have said", can also be used to mean "And I say". (Perhaps I should mention as much in the question.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that אֹמַר is the future tense I, and the extra אל"ף is dropped because it's hard to verbalize. (I think I read that in one of the grammar-oriented commentaries to the Torah. A quick search turns up three verses that fit: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0707.htm#4, http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a28.htm#8, http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0607.htm#8)

Comment: @ba Yes, it's the imperfect, and with the _vav_ it's the kinda-past imperfect, but doesn't always signify past tense. I don't know enough about this to comment much more intelligently than that, but I'm pretty sure it can mean "(and) I say". [WAF](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/u/3) will know more, I suspect, as may some other users here.

Comment: I'll try to find that commentary I mentioned. (I'm pretty sure it was Ibn Ezra somewhere in sefer BeReishis.)

Comment: If it is present tense, why would Moshe be quoting himself "And I say: .." instead of simply just saying it?

Comment: Come on, @ba, you know better than that. This is Vav HaHipuch. Most often it is written "VaYomer (... El)" or "VaYomar", but in this case HaShem is speaking in first "person", so it's "VaOmar". There's not a great mystery to that. Having said that, the question still stands. Is HaShem telling Moshe to quote Him, or is He speaking to Mosher to encourage him? +1 to msh210

Comment: @SethJ Well, I was saying that אֹמַר is the simple future tense, so וָאֹמַר should be the simple past tense ("I said"), not imperfect ("I *had* said"). I still didn't find that commentary I was looking for in the places where I remembered seeing the word אֹמַר, but I am pretty confident about it.

Comment: @ba, oh I totally missed the point you were making. I thought you were saying it's future. In the current form, not in the Vav-less form.

Comment: Cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29381

Answer (score 1):

Moses never promised אַעֲלֶה אֶתְכֶם מֵעֳנִי מִצְרַיִם but our tradition makes it very clear that G-d *did* (to Abraham). And certainly if Moses had made the promise, no one knew of it. The last thing they knew about him, he killed an Egyptian.

Therefore, my take is this:

> `Narrator:` G-d said further to Moses:
>
> `G-d said:` … Go gather the elders of Israel and tell them:
>
> `G-d tells Moses to say:` G-d, the god of your fathers, appeared to
>   me… saying:
>
> `Moses is told to say G-d said:` I paid attention to you and to what
>   was done to you in Egypt. And I `(G-d)` have said:
>
> `Moses is told to say G-d said that "G-d of the past" said:` I will
>   raise you from the poverty of Egypt….
>
> `G-d said:` And they will heed your voice….

Comment: That's the same as my first suggestion. Do you have some reasoning or source, or just the bare agreement with one of my suggestions over the other?

Comment: @msh210 My reason is that Moses never promised אַעֲלֶה אֶתְכֶם מֵעֳנִי מִצְרַיִם but G-d did (to Abraham).  And certainly if he did, no one knew Moses promised this.  The last thing they knew about him, he killed an Egyptian.

Comment: But וָאֹמַר, although I translated it as "And I have said", can also be used to mean "And I say". (Perhaps I should mention as much in the question.) Anyway, why not edit your reasoning into the answer?

Comment: @msh210 or "And I will say".  But our tradition makes it very clear that G-d made this promise and that G-d fulfilled the promise.  Not Moses.

Comment: (re your last comment) Moses *did* take us from Egypt. And this could be statement of what he would do.