# Who did "וַיֹּצִאֵנוּ" in Num. 20:16?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yetziat-mitzrayim, chukas

*Chukas* 20:16:

> וַנִּצְעַק אֶל ה׳ וַיִּשְׁמַע קֹלֵנוּ וַיִּשְׁלַח מַלְאָךְ וַיֹּצִאֵנוּ מִמִּצְרָיִם…‏

In translation:

> and we called out to God, and he heard our voice, and he sent a messenger, and he removed us from Egypt,…

Who's the last "he": God or the messenger?

Comment: Cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25633

Answer (score 2):

According to what we say on Pesach night in the Haggadah:

> וַיּוֹצִאֵנוּ יְיָ מִמִצְרַיִם - לֹא עַל יְדֵי מַלְאָךְ, וְלֹא עַל יְדֵי שָׂרָף, וְלֹא עַל יְדֵי שָׁלִיחַ, אֶלָּא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא בִּכְבוֹדוֹ וּבְעַצְמוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וְעָבַרְתִּי בְאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם בַּלַּיְלָה הַזֶּה, וְהִכֵּיתִי כָּל בְּכוֹר בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם מֵאָדָם וְעַד בְּהֵמָה, וּבְכָל אֱלֹהֵי מִצְרַיִם אֶעֱשֶׂה שְׁפָטִים. אֲנִי יְיָ.‏
>
> וְעָבַרְתִּי בְאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם בַּלַּיְלָה הַזֶּה - אֲנִי וְלֹא מַלְאָךְ & rlm;
>
> וְהִכֵּיתִי כָּל בְכוֹר בְּאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם - אֲנִי וְלֹא שָׂרָף‏
>
> וּבְכָל אֱלֹהֵי מִצְרַיִם אֶעֱשֶׂה שְׁפָטִים - אֲנִי ולֹא הַשָּׁלִיחַ.‏
>
> אֲנִי יְיָ - אֲנִי הוּא ולֹא אַחֵר.‏

And explained in Zohar Part 1 page 117a why no one but Hashem himself took them out - we must conclude that the Possuk in question must be referring to Hahsem.